# Return all rows grouped by year and month from date SQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have my prestations table and I want group all prestations by year-month from my created (date) column.

I tried group by YEAR() and MONTH() but it's only return 1 row.
For example, I want :

2019-01 :

prestation 1

prestation 2 
...

2019-02 :

prestation 1

...

[Database datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzQMY.jpg)
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDCgf.jpg)

How can I do this in SQL or in doctrine ? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example of your table, I'd like to see which format are your dates. And, yes you can do this in SQL but maybe you should parse the dates.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I added screen on my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the year and month values from the date field, then join them with CONCAT to create a year-month field, then group on that. Something like this.

`select CONCAT(year(mydate), '-', month(mydate)) as dateresult from test
group by dateresult;`

This is MySQL, not sure what you are using, and you will need to enter your own table and field names.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tried but I have 1 row by different CONCAT(year-month). How get all my prestations from YYYY-MM ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure exactly what you are asking here. Can you post some data from your table so I can see how it is structured ?

Comment: I added 2 screens on my question. My datas and my structure. Thank for help

Comment: OK perhaps this will help, try running this against your table `select CONCAT(year(created), '-', month(created)) as dateresult, label from test 
group by dateresult, label;`  If you change your data to have different values (e.g. if you had test1, test2, test3 etc. in the label field the resulting data will look a bit more meaningful.

Comment: Thank, I added 

`$prestations = [];

        foreach ($results as $result){
            $prestations[$result['dateresult']][] = $result;
        }
` 

and I get my array like I want, thank !